# mysql timediff where condition

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have to use a condition in the time diff of mysql. I have to modify the following query:-

```
select 
 bugs_team_user_view.bug_id,
 bugs_team_user_view.creation_ts 
from 
  bugs_team_user_view, bugs_activity 
where  
  bugs_team_user_view.team like "Red%" 
  and 

  timediff(
     (select bugs_activity.bug_when from bugs_activity where bugs_activity.added = "RESOLVED"),
  bugs_team_user_view.creation_ts) > "00:30:00"  

  and 
  bugs_team_user_view.bug_id=bugs_activity.bug_id
  and bugs_team_user_view.creation_ts < "2013-08-17 00:00:00" 
  and bugs_team_user_view.creation_ts >"2013-08-01 00:00:00";
```

Getting error:-

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to usenear 'bugs_team_user_view.creation_ts < "2013-08-17 00:00:00" and bugs_team_user_view.' at line 1

Please help

Comment: what modification you required?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do in external (application user) terms. Also, you may be able to do better with an explicit JOIN than with your comma-separated table list.

Comment: looks like a bug in your sql. suggest to apply the join clause in inline select as well (select b.bug_when from bugs_activity b
where b.added = "RESOLVED
and b.bug_id = v.bug_id)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
timediff(
     (select bugs_activity.bug_when from bugs_activity where bugs_activity.added = "RESOLVED"),
  bugs_team_user_view.creation_ts) > TIME('00:30:00')
```

it should work.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to usenear 'bugs_team_user_view.creation_ts < "2013-08-17 00:00:00" and bugs_team_user_view.' at line 1